# The relation between a real matrix and a complex matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ real matrices. Show that
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}=|\det(A+iB)|^{2}.$$

Comment: Show that you can transform the matrix into $$\begin{pmatrix} A+iB & 0\\ 0&A-iB\end{pmatrix}$$ by elementary transformations.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you give me some hints? To me, it is not immediate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What is

$$\begin{pmatrix}I & 0\\ iI & I \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A & -B\\ B & A\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}I & 0\\ iI & I \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A & -B\\ B & A\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}I & 0\\ -iI & I\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A+iB & -B\\ 0 & A-iB\end{pmatrix}$$ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & -i/2 \\ 1/2 & i/2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ i & -i \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A-iB & 0 \\ 0 & A+iB \end{pmatrix}$$

The determinants are $i/2,\det\begin{pmatrix}A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix},-2i$ and $|\det(A+iB)|^2$.

For a holomorphic transformation $\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$, the Jacobian is like $\begin{pmatrix}A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}$ due to the Cauchy-Riemann equation. On the other hand, if you complexify the (co)tangent bundle and make a coordinate change $dx_i,dy_i\rightarrow dz_i=dx_i+idy_i,d\bar{z}_i=dx_i-idy_i$, the Jacobian will be like $\begin{pmatrix}A-iB & 0 \\ 0 & \overline{A-iB} \end{pmatrix}$. And $\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & -i/2 \\ 1/2 & i/2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ i & -i \end{pmatrix}$ are just the transformation matrices.

Comment: This is technically incorrect. You cannot multiply matrices of order $2$, $n$, and $2$. You need $I$ next to each element of your transformation matrices.

Comment: @VedranŠego, Certainly.